# JQuery ajax - how to not escape quotes in url

Tags: jquery, ajax, kinvey

So I am using Kinvey to build a blog and I want to delete a post by accessing the Kinvey REST API. To do that I must pass a query like this:

```
https://baas.kinvey.com/appdata/kid_SyKVG7Vc/posts/?query={"_id":"57c57837befee76f50000a73"}
```

However when using jquery ajax it escapes the double quotes and I get this:

```
https://baas.kinvey.com/appdata/kid_SyKVG7Vc/posts/?query={%22_id%22:%2257c57f333db27c626a5aa393%22}
```

I don't jquery ajax to escape the quotes. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not be a problem. Because the double quotes has to be encoded to %22 in URL anyway.

I never use Kinvey before, but I just tried it by using the API console.
And the API console also send the request with the (%22)

just like the request you mentioned:

```
https://baas.kinvey.com/appdata/kid_SyKVG7Vc/posts/?query={%22_id%22:%2257c57f333db27c626a5aa393%22}
```

The problem that cause the deletion failed should be something else.
Can you double check the Kinvey's docs?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the framework you use, you probably want to use of the SDK's that Kinvey provides. There's a javascript sdk, and it'll allow you just to call something like

```
posts.removeById('id').then...
```

http://devcenter.kinvey.com/html5/guides/datastore#Deleting